# Handle events triggered from non-backbone page in backbone page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I have a framework written earlier for collecting real time data from site with only backbone.js. Now, I need to use this same framework for collecting data from site page which has hybrid arch (Headers and footers in backbone.js and content in plain html).

My question here is that how can I handle events like click, change on select etc. that happens in plain html the backbone way.

Note: In backbone arch, we are using mixins to load our event handlers onto the page js.(Eg: click #id: function_name). I cannot use traditional jQuery event handlers.

Comment: Why can't you use standard event handlers?

Comment: We have a framework which includes TDD and code for larger part of the site. So, the architect is persistent on using similar structure so that we do not add more mocks/stubs for these jquery selectors. Is there a way to use some helper js written in backbone which will register events from html page?

Comment: I think this is turning into a too broad discussion, but since you've decided to combine Backbone and non-Backbone parts, you should probably accept the fact that event handling for the vanilla DOM will be vanilla event handling. :) Not sure you'd be helped by "pretending" it's part of the Backbone implementation?

Comment: I have function as below - 
trackClickEvent: function () {
                $(document).on(change, .classname, function () {
                    func(function (view) {
                        ...
                    }, this);
                });
            }
I am returning this so that when the page loads this function is loaded from Backbone arch code on to the DOM. So when the event is triggered in non-backbone page it gets registered and calls the function. Is there a way I can wrap $(document).on(...) inside another method like a wrapper function and still be able to handle events?